# Prove that the mapping $U(16)$ to itself by $x \rightarrow x^3$ is an automorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Prove that the mapping $U(16) = \{{1,3,5,7,9,11,13,15}\}$ to itself by $x \rightarrow x^3$ is an automorphism. What about $x \rightarrow x^5$ and $x \rightarrow x^7$? any generalization?

So far i have prove the first part.

Let $\psi : x \rightarrow x^3$,
 Since $U(16)$ is a group under multiplication modulo 16, hence $U(16)$ is closed under mult.modulo 16. Take any $x,y \in U(16)$ and let $\psi(x) = \psi(y)$, then $x^3 = y^3mod(16)$. This implies $16 | (x^3 - y^3)$ and since $x^3$ and $y^3$ always less than 16, then $x = ymod( 16)$. So that $\psi$ is one-to-one. By this, it clear that $\psi$ is also *onto*.

Now since $\psi(xy)=x^{3}y^{3}mod(16) = x^{3}mod(16)y^{3}mod(16) = \psi(x)\psi(y)$ and $\psi$ is both one-to-one and *onto*, thus $\psi$ is an automorphism.

For proving $x \rightarrow x^5$ and $x \rightarrow x^7$, just use the same step above. But how to generalize?

My conclusion so far is that $\psi : x \rightarrow x^n$ where $n$ is odd positive integers are an automorphism. Because if i take $n=2$, then  $\psi(3) = 9 = \psi(5)$ and $\psi$ is not one-to-one.

Comment: You have $U(13)$ and $U(16)$. Which one is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that if $x$ is odd, then by Euler's Theorem we have $x^8\equiv 1\pmod{16}$. Indeed by direct calculation $x^4\equiv 1\pmod{16}$. So once you have done $x^1$ and $x^3$, the fact that $x^k$ is an automorphism for $k$ odd is automatic.

Comment: Thanks, so by Euler's theorem, every $x \in U(16)$ has the property $ x^{2n} \equiv 1 (mod 16) $ which means that $\psi : x \rightarrow x^{2n}$ is not one-to-one?

Comment: Not $x^{2n}$, Euler's Theorem would give $x^{8n}$, but it is actually $x^{4n}$ which is always $\equiv 1$. But we have $x^2\equiv 1\pmod{8}$, and this is enough to show that $x^{2n}$ is never one to one.